# html rule VS css rule on "google's inspect element"

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm trying to change the "Width" rule in the css style above.
in the "inspect element" you can see that the width is 1008px.
i don't want it to be 1008px but it won't let me change it at the css style you can see that it's "deleted" ... 
i'm working with WordPress.
any idea ?

Comment: you may need to use `!important` to override inline styles if that's what you're refering to

Answer (score 0):

First add the css in

```
element.style {
}
```

secondly try adding `!important` at the end of the style

Answer (score 0):

Element style always overrides css style.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp